# Forgot what I set my underlying environmental variable in node.js. Is there a way to check it in the command line?

Tags: node.js, bash

I can't recall what I set as the definition of an environmental variable in my code for Node.js? I've tried

`jsbach:~/workspace/drdenver (master) $ process.env.MLAB_URI
bash: process.env.MLAB_URI: command not found`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming they have previously been [exported](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58814/how-do-i-add-environment-variables):

- `echo $MLAB_URI` for that one, or
- `printenv` for your whole environment.

[`process`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html) is part of the core Node API, and has nothing to do with bash, (which is where you appear to be asking about).